# C# - Get a List<string> data from a form to another

Tags: c#, list, listbox, datasource

I want to ask help about my problem. My problem is that I can't get the values of a List from another form and transfer it into a ListBox in another form.. I want to make the elements of the List to be the datasource of the list box.

These are the screenshot of my program.

This is the code of my Form1.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<string> list = new List<string>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        form2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add("!");

        MessageBox.Show(list.Count.ToString());
    }
```

Then in my Form2, I created an instance of Form1 and called the List list but when the Form2 loads, the ListBox is not populated with the data, and it appears that the List list doesn't contain any data when Form2 loads. Here is my code in Form2.

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        listBox1.DataSource = form1.list;
    }
```

Any idea how i can solve the problem? I tried everything that I can do but I can't solve the problem. Sorry for my mistakes, I'm only a beginner in C#, in my course and here in stackoverflow. Thank you in advance.

Comment: create a constructor on form2 accepting list<string> and pass value like. public Form2(List<string> collection){//do logic}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Form1, change:

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

To:

```
form2.ShowDialog(this); // pass in this Form1 instance as the "Owner"
```

Then in Form2, change:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    listBox1.DataSource = form1.list;
}
```

To:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
    listBox1.DataSource = f1.list;
}
```

Comment: With this approach, you can only use Form2 with Form1 (since we're casting `Owner` to Type Form1).  If you plan on using Form2 with other Forms, then use the Constructor approach posted by baryo.  This approach is a "tightly coupled" approach, while baryo's is a "loosely coupled" approach.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of `Form2` you're creating a new instance of `Form1` with new `ListBox` object, which is empty.
You should pass the `ListBox`'s Datasource to `Form2` through its constructor.

```
public class Form2
{
     public Form2(Array arr)
     {
        listBox.DataSource = arr;
     }
}
```

It's important NOT to pass the `Form` object directly, as to not create coupling between those forms - we're only interested in the data.

Comment: If you use this approach then change `Form2 form2 = new Form2();` to `Form2 form2 = new Form2(list);`.